# Approaches to "reimage" a device

Tags: linux, windows

I need to replace a Windows OS by a Linux on a x86 device. I would need to re-image this device without physical intervention ideally.

I thought I could have some sort of file server where the device could pull this image, but I cannot complete the puzzle in my mind yet, like how it will launch the installation.

Is this possible? Do exist tools for this?

In case physical intervention is required, what level of automation I could expected? Can I just prepare a USB stick with the installation process pre-scripted, plug it in and get the device upgraded?

Comment: What you can do highly depends on the device you want to upgrade, e.g. does it support PXE booting?

Comment: As people already mentioned under your previous question, which you didn't react to any further, full automation is absolutely possible, and very normal, as soon as you boot any installation medium. And that can be achieved from Windows as well.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply upgrade from Windows to Linux.

First you back up your data offsite (to a different PC or media) and verify your backup integrity however you want. In case you want to be able to return to Windows full disk imaging is highly advised (there are multiple free Windows and Linux applications for that).

You either

- Repartition your disk to allow for Linux installation - Linux can share the EFI system (boot) partition with Windows, so you can enjoy multiboot safely nowadays. Cut let's say 50GB from any of your Windows partitions, that will be more than enough for your Linux installation. You can then mount your existing NTFS partitions and use them in Linux if you need more space for your files.

Or:

- Wipe everything and install Linux from scratch.

That all must be done on site, manually. Doing so remotely is possible but extremely ill-advised unless you're an expert in Linux/Windows/PC hardware in general.